# Spree grab all products for taxon and children taxons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I basically want to grab the following in a view:

All the products for the current taxon, and then all the products for the taxon's children. What's the best way to do this? Is there a method already?

Answer (score 8):

```
taxon_products = current_taxon.products
children_products = current_taxon.children.includes(:products).map(&:products).
                                  flatten.compact.uniq
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @PinnyM is fine if you only need to search one level of children, but if you want to find *all* the products under a taxon, you can use [the `in_taxon` scope](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/842b3e70cb26212e5351a6fc85ce27417c5a2693/core/app/models/spree/product/scopes.rb#L61-L82) like this:

```
children_products = Spree::Product.in_taxon(current_taxon)
```

Comment: This should be in the API documentation.